# python pool shows only one PID > is this being processed in parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I'm quite newbie in python, so please bear with my newbie question.
I'm trying to run a set of tasks in a pool to speed things up but I'm not seeing an improvement in speed.
I have tried to run it in two different ways, to figure out was happening and my output only shows one PID being used. Does this mean that I'm not using pools correctly?

I did a small mock based on the script I'm trying to run:

```py
import sys, shutil, time, 
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
        
def download(link):
    print(os.getpid())
    print("done!"
    
def download(links):
    print("done 2 !")
    for link in links:
            print(os.getpid())
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_links=[...]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)             
    #option 1
    #   [pool.apply_async(download(link),(link,)) for link in list_of_links]
    #option 2
    pool.map(download(list_of_links),list_of_links)
```

The output  shows the same PID (in each call)

For option 1

```
22300
done!
22300
done!
22300
```

for option 2

```
done 2 !
20328
20328
20328
20328
```

Is this the normal behavior ? or ? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: No need to pass list_of_links in the download function when you pass it in map function. Just the download function will do. pool.map(download, list_of_links)

Comment: You define the `download` name twice. And pass the execution result of the function to `pool.map`. Instead, just pass it `pool.map(download, list_of_links)`

Comment: Yep that worked. I question myself how I ended up with that solution. Maybe to fix a lesser error I ended in a dead end. Thanks